# Difference between username/password in react-native-keychain?

Tags: react-native, react-native-keychain

I'm integrating with [react-native-keychain](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain) and I'm somewhat confused about the `setGenericPassword` and `getGenericPassword` methods. What exactly is the difference between `username` and `password` for the `setGenericPassword(username, password, ...)` method when to access the stored information we simply call `getGenericPassword` without any parameters.

Is the password even doing anything or is the entire point just to store two strings? Is this where the sensitive data should be stored? I've read the API description and looked over the example repository but it wasn't clear to me.